# keyboard friendly AJAX search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented the AJAX search which is similar to the example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp). In this example, you might notice that you can switch between the search results using `TAB` key. In my search results, there is a table in the following format:

```
*Client*  *Status*  *Hostname*
<client1>   value     value
<client2>   value     value
<client3>   value     value
```

`Client1, client2, client3` are actually hyperlinks and are in the class `search_result_entry`. So, when down arrow key is pressed, I would like the focus to go to the `client1` link.  The `TAB` key works here, but the arrow key would be more intuitive. The values in status and hostname are not clickable. Also, note that I am using `overflow: auto` so if there are too many search results, the scrollbar shows up. In this case, hitting the TAB key twice gets me to the first search result.

I was doing trial and error and tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
if (e.which == 40){    // 40 is the ASCII for down arrow key
    $("#keyword").focusout();
    $("#results").focus(function(){
            $(this).next("td").focus();
    });
}
```

How do I get the focus to move to the search results using the down arrow key and navigate in it using the down/up arrow keys?

Comment: can you post your code at jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

```
//Keep track of the focused element
var focusedElement = null;

// update it on focus
$("#results").focus(function(){
  focusedElement = this;
});
```

And somewhere in your handler:

```
//... code
if (e.which == 40){    // 40 is the ASCII for down arrow key
  if(focusedElement) $(focusedElement).next().focus();
  else $('#results').somethingToGetYourFirstElementDependingOnYourCode().focus();
}
//... more code
```

The first part will keep track of the currently focused element (if any) and the second part will update the focused element (which will trigger the first part and update the currently focused element)

Comment: Sorry, that dint work for me. I had your code placed in the onkeyup event where I am implementing the search function. However, it dint go through.