# Keyboard friendly AJAX search within an HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, keyboard-events

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form action="whatever.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" onKeyUp="ajax_search()" name="search" id="search">

    // THE AJAX FUNCTION UPDATES THE DIV BELOW
    <div id="search_results"></div>

    <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
    <input type="text" name="cost" id="cost">
    <input type="text" name="discount" id="discount">

    <input type="submit" value="GO">

</form>
```

I have an `AJAX` function (`ajax_search()`) that points to a `PHP` file that returns items from a database table that are similar to what is input in the `search` input. (`... WHERE code LIKE '"$code"%'`)

No problems so far. The items returned are done so in the following format:

```
$output .= '<p onClick="insert_item(' .json_encode($code). ')">' .$code. '</p>';
```

When the `<p>` tag is clicked, the `<form>` is updated with the item (`$code`) and all it's relative information. This works great!

I am now looking to add in keyboard functionality to the `AJAX` search. The user should be able to 'select' the items using the keyboard arrows.

I read a similar discussion here: [keyboard friendly AJAX search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848305/keyboard-friendly-ajax-search)

The discussion doesn't go very far and the end result was that the code did not work for the OP.

Also, because the `search_results` div is displayed amongst a `<form>` already and the `<input id="search">` is focused, the 'ENTER' key will activate the `submit` button instead of calling the `insert_item()` function. I may be able to sort this issue out on my own using `javascript` `if()` statements and ASCII codes.

Please help me in selecting the searched items using keyboard arrow keys?

**UPDATE**

I have tried giving the serached `<p>` items an `<a>` tag for **tab** selection. But when I hit **tab**, all that happens is the next `<input>` in the `<form>` is focused.

Answer (score 1):

I would catch the charCodes in an if statement something like this:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.charCode === 38) {  // Up arrow
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action
        currentSelection++; // Update the current selection
    } else if(e.charCode === 40) { // Down Arrow
        // ...etc....
    }
});
```

Theres a pretty helpful list of the charCodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

You should be able to catch any of they keys this way (tab, enter, arrows etc..) and prevent their actions using e.preventDefault()